# Error while using valiable in Jquery.val() funciton

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I got no output when I use variable in val() function instead of fixed value. How can I fix this error.

Example: In the below example, when I use variable `($data="Glenn Quagmire")`, I get no output.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    <?php $data="Glenn Quagmire";  ?>
    $("input:text").val($data);
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Name: <input type="text" name="user"></p>
<button>Set the value of the input field</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Regards

Comment: What are you getting in `<?php $data="Glenn Quagmire";  ?>`?

Comment: `$data` is a php variable not a javascript one. Don't mix languages needlessly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use like this:

```
$("input:text").val("<?php echo $data; ?>");
```

Full code

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("button").click(function(){
 <?php $data="Glenn Quagmire";  ?>
 $("input:text").val("<?php echo $data; ?>");
 });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: @user15662 : this may help you. :)

Comment: @user15662 show me how you are using? it's working perfectly for me :)

Comment: Below is code that i am using for it.                                            <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("button").click(function(){
 <?php $data="Glenn Quagmire";  ?>
$("input:text").val(<?php echo json_encode($data); ?>);
 });
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Name: <input type="text" name="user"></p>
<button>Set the value of the input field</button>

</body>
</html>

Comment: @user15662 what is the extension of your file? means it's a .htm or .php file?

Comment: Extention of file is .html

Comment: @user15662 ok so i got the problem.  .html not suppurt php code.so just save your file with .php extension and use this line $("input:text").val("<?php echo $data; ?>"); to your code. it should work.

Comment: @user15662 let me know.if it is working for you :) enjoy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69198/discussion-between-priyank-and-user15662).

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript running in the browser cannot access variables from a PHP program (which has finished running on another computer before delivering the page to the browser so the variable does't even exist any more).

You have to make PHP output the data to the JavaScript.

You can encode it using `json_encode` (because JSON is (more or less) a subset of JavaScript literal syntax). This will add quotes as needed and escape any special characters in your data (you don't have any in your example, but this is a safe, general approach that protects you from XSS).

```
$("input:text").val(<?php echo json_encode($data); ?>);
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use "$" for variables (that's PHP) in jQuery.

```
<?php echo 'data="Glenn Quagmire";';  ?>
$("input:text").val(data);
```

Comment: I disagree. The same can be said the other way around. In jQuery, variables starting with $ usually represent jQuery objects, although these days people seem to have stopped using that convention...

Answer (score 1):

Use `<?= $variable ?>` to embed variable values in HTML, e.g.:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        <?php $data="Glenn Quagmire";  ?>
        $("input:text").val("<?= $data ?>");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Name: <input type="text" name="user"></p>
<button>Set the value of the input field</button>

</body>
</html>
```